# Shrink children to fit parent

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-size div with variable amount of child elements. I don't know the size of the children in advance. The goal is to shrink them to fit the parent.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed green;
}
.parent * {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x400" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x250" />
</div>
```

`max-width` etc seems to *individually* shrink a child to be no larger than the parent; Any elements after the first burst out.

Ideas to contain them all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CSS

- [`display` with `table` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to make the nodes to conform within it's parent's dimensions.
- [`position` with `relative` for parent and `absolute` for children](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) in order to keep them within their parent's borders.

In the demo both parents and images are identical but with one exception: *the first parent is 200x200px and the second parent is 100x100px.* As we can see, the children have conformed perfectly within the parent's borders regardless of how parent's dimensions are.

**Details are commented in  demo**

### Demo

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  /* Behaves like a table
  || which means that any 
  || table elements and elements
  || styled to behave like a 
  || table element will conform
  || to it's parent while maintaining
  || it's aspect ratio.
  */
  display: table;
  /* This will enable children to stay 
  || within it's borders if they are
  || absolutely positioned
  */
  position: relative;
}

.ver2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent * {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* Behaves as a <td> which means
  || it will naturally shrink to
  || conform to the dimensions
  || of it's parent if it is a
  || table or an element styled
  || to behave like a table and 
  || keep it's aspect ratio.
  */
  display: table-cell;
  /* It will stay within the confines
  || of the borders of it's parent
  || (unless it's given negative 
  || values)
  */
  position: absolute;
}

img:first-of-type {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Layered on top of img1
  || to show it's position
  || within the parent
  */
  z-index: 1;
  /* used to show where img1 is. */
  opacity: .5;
}

img:last-of-type {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.demoOnly {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='demoOnly'>
  <div class="parent ver2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x400/f00/fcf?text=img1" />
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x250/fc0/f00?text=img2" />
  </div>
  <span>Parent is 100x100px<br>
img1 is AR 5:8 - 62.5x100px<br>
img2 is AR 6:5 - 100x83px</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x400/f00/fcf?text=img1" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x250/fc0/f00?text=img2" />
</div>
<span>Parent is 200x200px<br>
img1 is AR 5:8 - 125x200px<br>
img2 is AR 6:5 - 200x166px</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this using `position: absolute` in css properties. Whenever you shrink it, the child will fit to the parent. If you have any problem with it, please comment below. Happy Coding! :)

```css
.parent{
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #363636;
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
}


.child{
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example child is already smaller than parent therefor there is no issue. OP is asking for a solution wherein the **child is larger than parent**. `position` property is only half of the solution see my answer. The parent also has fixed dimensions specified by OP to which you have given percentages, Edit your child with `height:400px` and you'll see what is OP's problem.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this**

```
.parent *
    {
    width:100%;
    }
```